# SQL - Way to find duplicate fields within multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, duplicates

I'm wondering if there's a way to return duplicates of parts of rows.

IDTable setup:

```
ID# | Customer  | EventID#
1   | Steve     | 123
2   | Steve     | 123
3   | John      | 987
4   | John      | 924
```

Since Steve and 123 appear twice together, I want to treat that as a 'duplicate' even though they have two different ID#'s.  And if there's a 'duplicate', ideally I'd like to only return columns: ID#, Customer & EventID#. So for the above IDTable example, only return:

```
1   | Steve | 123
2   | Steve | 123
```

By running the following, it counts each ID + Customer + EventID# separately and returns all Count values as 1 (I'm using SQL Server 2008):

```
SELECT ID#, Customer, EventID#, COUNT({fn CONCAT(Customer,EventID#)})
FROM IDTable
GROUP BY ID#, Customer, EventID#
HAVING COUNT({fn CONCAT(Customer,EventID#)}) > 1
```

If I take out the ID# from the Select, it'l work but then we won't know what the ID#'s are.

EDIT:
I'm joining in the select columns from other tables.  I initially left those out for simplicity sake by when trying to apply solutions below I'm getting confused.  Apologies!  Here's what is more in line with what I'm using:

```
SELECT A.ID#, C.Customer, E.EventID#
FROM IDTable A
INNER JOIN CustomerTable C
   ON C.AccountID = A.AccountID
INNER JOIN EventTable E
   ON E.AccountType = C.AccountType
WHERE C.StatusID = 'Active'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-Join should do the trick:

```
SELECT     A.ID#, A.Customer, A.EventID#
FROM       Table A
INNER JOIN Table A2 ON A.Customer = A2.Customer 
                   AND A.EventID# = A2.EventID# 
                   AND A.ID# <> A2.ID#
```

**Edit for your joins:**

You can still use a self-join, just with derived tables like so:

```
SELECT     A.ID#, A.Customer, A.EventID#
FROM       (SELECT ID#, Customer, EventID#
            FROM IDTable A
            INNER JOIN CustomerTable C ON C.AccountID = A.AccountID
            INNER JOIN EventTable E ON E.AccountType = C.AccountType
            WHERE C.StatusID = 'Active') A
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID#, Customer, EventID#
            FROM IDTable A
            INNER JOIN CustomerTable C ON C.AccountID = A.AccountID
            INNER JOIN EventTable E ON E.AccountType = C.AccountType
            WHERE C.StatusID = 'Active') A2 ON A.Customer = A2.Customer 
                                           AND A.EventID# = A2.EventID# 
                                           AND A.ID# <> A2.ID#
```

And cleaner with `#TEMP`:

```
SELECT A.ID#, C.Customer, E.EventID#
INTO #TEMP
FROM IDTable A
INNER JOIN CustomerTable C
   ON C.AccountID = A.AccountID
INNER JOIN EventTable E
   ON E.AccountType = C.AccountType
WHERE C.StatusID = 'Active'
;

SELECT     A.ID#, A.Customer, A.EventID#
FROM       #TEMP A
INNER JOIN #TEMP A2 ON A.Customer = A2.Customer 
                   AND A.EventID# = A2.EventID# 
                   AND A.ID# <> A2.ID#
```

Comment: Interesting.  So essentially a series of subqueries joined together?  I'll give it a shot...

Comment: I would not do that though. You can first SELF JOIN and only then JOIN with CustomerTable and EventTable.

Comment: @bojackh Exactly.  In fact, if you are going to use this a lot, the cleanest way would be to create a temp table or CTE and do the self-join that way (essentially the first query).  The derived tables do the same thing, but they will require SQL to run the query twice.  Side note, you may or may not have to mess with the inner aliases if those columns exist in multiple tables.

Comment: @caiohamamura No you cannot.. Columns from each of those tables are required for the self-join predicate.

Comment: But both predicates will depend only on AccountID, because an AccountID will JOIN to a Customer which willl have an AccountType. So they both depend only on AccountID.

Comment: In your first query (Not the #Temp) - the select items within the subqueries (ID#, Customer, EventID#), do you not have to assign aliases to each?

Comment: @bojackh You do only if those columns exist in more than one of those tables

Comment: This one worked for me so far.  Yes it does take quite a while to run and might play with a Temp table but at least it runs and returns what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most version of SQL support window functions.  The easiest way to solve this is:

```
select id, customer, eventid#
from (select i.*, count(*) over (partition by customer, eventid#) as cnt
      from idtable i
     ) i
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: I'm actually joining the customer & EventID from other tables.  So when I try to run this I'm getting the error "The multi-part identifier "C.Customer" could not be bound" after the 'partition by'.  Let me know if I need to edit my initial query to incorporate the joins; left those out for simplicity sake but now looks like I need to add them..

Comment: @bojackh . . . There is not table alias called `c` in this solution, so it is entirely unclearly how this could generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.*
FROM
    IDTable i
    INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT Customer, EventID#
       FROM IDTable
       GROUP BY ID#, Customer, EventID#
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t
    ON i.Customer = t.Customer
    AND i.EventId# = t.EventId#
```

There may be other ways of doing this and if you tag your specific rdbms (sql-server, oracle, mysql etc.) I am sure you will get additional answers but here is one way to do it which is to use your query (without the ID column) to identify the duplicates and then match it back to your original table via a inner join.

Comment: Hi, I edited my initial query to include the initial joins I had from the select statement.  Trying to figure out how to incorporate your solution with my edited query.

Comment: Which rdbms are you using? mysql? Microsoft sql server? oracle????? there are a lot of good answers above but depending on your answer to which technology you are using will allow us all to make our answers simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: MS SQL Server.  Thanks

Comment: use gordon's answer you can do all of your joins etc in the sub select. SQL will interpret it almost exactly like what I am suggesting just less code and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

From @Aaron_D's answer I'd not join subqueries, instead you can do:

```
SELECT A.ID#, C.Customer, E.EventID#
FROM IDTable A
INNER JOIN IDTable B ON A.ID# = B.ID#
                    AND A.AccountID <> B.AccountID
INNER JOIN CustomerTable C
   ON C.AccountID = A.AccountID
INNER JOIN EventTable E
   ON E.AccountType = C.AccountType
WHERE C.StatusID = 'Active'
```

Since both CustomerTable AND EventTable are in last instance derived from AccountID it will work fine and will be faster.